# How to use OnDrop on non-UI elements?

Tags: unity, c#, input, unity-ui, card-game

I'm new to Unity and coding (C#), so sorry if this is a novice question.

Is the `OnDrop` function only usable for UI elements? I am currently making an ARPG Card game and I draw a hand of cards and can play these cards on enemies.

I currently have it working if I drag and drop a card onto other UI elements, but if I want to drag and drop the card onto an enemy (which then theoretically calls a function) it doesn't seem to work. BUT, if I drop the card onto its health bar (which is in the canvas and rendered into worldspace) it does seem to call the `OnDrop` function.

This is a 2D project and the enemies are set up with mesh renderers and 2D colliders.

How can I make `OnDrop` work if I just wanted to drop the card onto the enemy itself, and NOT its health bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use Event System events with non-UI objects, you need to do the following:

1. Add a Physics Raycaster component the camera whose view you want to "click through" or "drop through". (Or a Physics 2D Raycaster if you're using 2D physics)

   Optionally, you can set an Event Mask to control which physics layers should be clickable/drop-onto-able this way and which should be ignored / treated as transparent to clicks.
2. Add a physics collider to the 3D object you want to click/drop onto. (Or a 2D collider to the 2D object you want to click). This collider defines the volume of space that "counts" as a click/drop on this object. You can make it larger or a simpler shape than the object itself to make it easier to target with your mouse/finger.
3. Add an Event Trigger component to the object you want to receive the clicks / drops, or a script that implements the [`IDropHandler` interface](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IDropHandler.html).

The reason why UI objects work with this automatically is because a newly-created UI canvas already has a Graphic Raycaster component on it by default. This does the same job as the Physics Raycaster in step 1 - mapping the pointer position on the screen to objects "under" that point - but for UI objects instead. UI objects also serve as their own collider shapes for picking purposes, as long as their "Raycast Target" checkbox is ticked.

Comment: This did it! The only thing I was missing was step one. Thank you very much for the prompt reply and the detailed explanation!